# On xeditable grid where move a cursor same column when user press the Tab key

Tags: javascript, angularjs, x-editable

I'm using [Xeditable](http://vitalets.github.io/angular-xeditable/#editable-table) grid.Could you tell me how to move a cursor same column when user press the Tab key ? i.e move on **Name** column.Thanks in advance.

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sampath_lokuge/NfPcH/9867/)**

*Note :* By default it moves horizontally on the row.I need it moves vertically on the column.

[image]

```
<h4>Angular-xeditable Editable table (Bootstrap 3)</h4>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="Ctrl">
 <form editable-form name="tableform" onaftersave="saveTable()" oncancel="cancel()" shown="true">

    <!-- table -->
    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-condensed">
      <tr style="font-weight: bold">
        <td style="width:40%">Name</td>
        <td style="width:30%">Status</td>
        <td style="width:30%">Group</td>
        <td style="width:30%"><span ng-show="tableform.$visible">Action</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="user in users | filter:filterUser">
        <td>
          <!-- editable username (text with validation) -->
          <span editable-text="user.name" e-form="tableform" onbeforesave="checkName($data, user.id)">
            {{ user.name || 'empty' }}
          </span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <!-- editable status (select-local) -->
          <span editable-select="user.status" e-form="tableform" e-ng-options="s.value as s.text for s in statuses">
            {{ showStatus(user) }}
          </span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <!-- editable group (select-remote) -->
          <span editable-select="user.group" e-form="tableform" onshow="loadGroups()" e-ng-options="g.id as g.text for g in groups">
            {{ showGroup(user) }}
          </span>
        </td>
        <td><button type="button" ng-show="tableform.$visible" ng-click="deleteUser(user.id)" class="btn btn-danger pull-right">Del</button></td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <!-- buttons -->
    <div class="btn-edit">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-show="!tableform.$visible" ng-click="tableform.$show()">
        edit
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-form" ng-show="tableform.$visible">
      <button type="button" ng-disabled="tableform.$waiting" ng-click="addUser()" class="btn btn-default pull-right">add row</button>
      <button type="submit" ng-disabled="tableform.$waiting" class="btn btn-primary">save</button>
      <button type="button" ng-disabled="tableform.$waiting" ng-click="tableform.$cancel()" class="btn btn-default">cancel</button>
    </div> 

  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `e-tabindex` to your columns like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ckosloski/g807jm1j/2/).

```
 <tr ng-repeat="user in users | filter:filterUser">
        <td>
          <!-- editable username (text with validation) -->
          <span editable-text="user.name" e-form="tableform" onbeforesave="checkName($data, user.id)" e-tabindex="1">
            {{ user.name || 'empty' }}
          </span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <!-- editable status (select-local) -->
          <span editable-select="user.status" e-form="tableform" e-ng-options="s.value as s.text for s in statuses" e-tabindex="2">
            {{ showStatus(user) }}
          </span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <!-- editable group (select-remote) -->
          <span editable-select="user.group" e-form="tableform" onshow="loadGroups()" e-ng-options="g.id as g.text for g in groups" e-tabindex="3">
            {{ showGroup(user) }}
          </span>
        </td>
        <td><button type="button" ng-show="tableform.$visible" ng-click="deleteUser(user.id)" class="btn btn-danger pull-right" tabindex="4">Del</button></td>
      </tr>
```